# Using Jasypt to secure spring boot database password, but received error

Tags: jasypt

This is what i did with Jasypt for springboot:

1. i have confiured my maven dependency as follows:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
       <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. then i have configured my application.properties

> (java -cp jasypt-1.9.3.jar
>   org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI input="mypassword"
>   password=123 algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES):
>
> spring.datasource.password=ENC(YZ2Lt/juEKhtYIIGNNdm7gmy9p0xrFM7) 
>       jasypt.encryptor.password=123
>
> jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES

3. when i run my application i've got this:

> Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to
>   java.lang.String:
>   Reason: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password'
>   to java.lang.String
>
> Action: Update your application's configuration

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? did i miss anything? Thanks in advance!